# What are the differences between these two Scala code segments regarding postfix toString method?

Tags: scala, unary-operator

I am learning postfix unary operators in Scala.
The following can not compile:

```
val result = 43 toString    
println(result)
```

However if I add one empty line inbetween the two lines, the code compile and produces right output:

```
val result = 43 toString

println(result)
```

What is the difference between these two segments?
BTW, I did not add "import scala.language.postfixOps".

Comment: Perhaps my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932071/tolist-on-range-with-suffix-notation-causes-type-mismatch/37932348#37932348) can clarify.

Comment: I would advise to just not use postfix operators and spend your time on more useful features.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Accoding to the official docs referred in @YuvalItzchakov's answer, postfix operators style for general alphanumeric-named methods is indeed not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is clearer if we use some other operator instead of `toString`.

```
// This parses as `List(1,2,3,4) ++ List(4,5,6)` 
List(1,2,3,4) ++
List(4,5,6)
```

Basically, in order to make the above work, while also allowing things like `foo ?` (a postfix operator), Scala needs to know when it is OK to stop expecting a second argument (and accept that the expression is a postfix operator).

Its solution is give up on finding a second argument if there is an interceding new line.

Comment: I absolutely _loathe_ Scala's irregular parses. I've left my answer as a community wiki so that others with more charitable views of this "feature" may edit it if they wish.

Comment: In the toString method case, why would toString expects a second argument, considering the method signature of java.lang.Object.toString()? Is binary operator somehow the default in Scala?

Comment: @Tyler During the parsing stage of the compilation process the compiler doesn't know yet how many arguments a method may or may not expect.

Comment: @Tyler: to be more precise, the number of parameters is a matter of *semantics*, whereas postfix vs. infix is a matter of *syntax*. They live in completely different worlds. It would of course be *possible* to create a language where the number of parameters is part of the *syntax*, either explicitly as in Erlang (where e.g. `toString/1` and `toString/2` would be different functions) or implicitly (which would mean that the parser needs to understand which identifiers are in scope at which point and the definition of those identifiers, IOW the entire compiler needs to be part of the parser).